# "PermitRootLogin no" in sshd config doesn't prevent `su -`

Tags: centos, ssh, root, su

The problem is that I really don't know if I am confused with PermitRootLogin or it is not working well.
I put it in the sshd_config, and when I connect via ssh, I am able to do `su -` in order to have root permissions. So shouldn't `PermitRootLogin no` permit me that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`PermitRootLogin` only configures whether root can login directly via ssh (e.g. `ssh root@example.com`). When you login using a different user account, whatever you do in your shell is not influenced by `sshd`'s config.

From `man sshd_config`:

```
 PermitRootLogin
     Specifies whether root can log in using ssh(1).  The argument must be “yes”, “without-password”, “forced-commands-only”, or “no”.  The default is “yes”.
     […]
     If this option is set to “no”, root is not allowed to log in.
```

---

You can however use your `login.defs` or `pam` config to limit which users can use the `su` command: [Server Fault: Disable su on machine](//serverfault.com/q/69216/154554)

Comment: So it doesn't means doing `su -`, it means login as root. But if I use allowUsers without allowing root, it is not needed the `permitRootLogin`?Thanks.

Comment: @QuicoLlinaresLlorens I would leave `PermitRootLogin` as "no" regardless as a secondary control measure.

Comment: I also would set the `root` default shell to `/bin/false` to have one more security layer.

Answer (score -3):

with PermitRootLogin yes, 
you can directly ssh as root.

```
ssh root@destination
```

If you want to disable sudo su for root access:

Lets says you have list of users(sudoers) that are allowed to do sudo on destination. This list is maintained at /etc/sudoers file.

1) Allow ssh for users that do not have sudo permissions in /etc/ssh/sshd. conf:
    AllowUsers sudoers

2) DenyUsers directive in /etc/ssh/sshd.conf:
    DenyUsers nonsudoers